# safeAreaInsets issues in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I´m developing a game and now I have noticed that it was not looking as I expected on iPhone X. What I need is to place a label on `top right corner`, on iPhone X the label was not showing at all. So I read about `Safe Area` and came up with this solution:

GameViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.view.layoutSubviews()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print("viewDidLayoutSubviews")
    print(self.view.safeAreaInsets.top)
    print(self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

And in my GameScene I´m doing this when the user

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    var label = SKLabelNode()
    if let safeAreaInsets = self.view?.safeAreaInsets {
        var y: CGFloat = 0.0
        if safeAreaInsets.top == 0.0 { iPhone SE, 6/7/8, Plus
            y = self.frame.height - 10
        } else { // iPhone X
            y = frame.maxY - safeAreaInsets.top - 5
        }
        label.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width -100, y: y)
    }

    label.text = "Highscore: 0"
    label.zPosition = 5
}
```

## Two questions on this:

### 1:

This works, but do I really need to make the check if `safeAreaInsets.top == 0.0` to detect if I need to use the `safeAreaInsets` for iPhone X? Shouldn´t the safe area fbe the same either phone?

2:
To be able to get the `safeAreaInsets` I need to call `self.view.setNeedsLayout(), self.view.layoutIfNeeded(), self.view.layoutSubviews()` (probably not all but some of them). If I don´t use this all `safeAreaInsets` is always 0.0. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

```
   private func safeAreaInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            return UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets ?? .zero
        } else {
            return .zero
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        let safeAreaBottom = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        let safeAreaLeft = window.safeAreaInsets.left
        let safeAreaRight = window.safeAreaInsets.right
        let safeAreaTop = window.safeAreaInsets.top
    }
```

}